# Implicit convesion in to method?

Tags: scala

How is the .to method found in below :

```
'a' to 'j'
```

This is same as :

```
('a'.to('j'))
```

But .to method is not found on class Char ? Is there some kind of implicit conversion going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `scala` package `Predef` object, which is always automatically imported, you'll find that it extends `LowPriorityImplicits` which contains

```
@inline implicit def charWrapper(c: Char) = 
      new runtime.RichChar(c)
```

this method converts your `Char` to `runtime.RichChar`

`RichChar` in it's turn extends `runtime.IntegralProxy[Char]` which has method:

```
def to(end: T): NumericRange.Inclusive[T] = 
      NumericRange.inclusive(self, end, num.one)
```

it is what you get.

If you decompile your code and you'll see:

```
new RichChar(Predef..MODULE$.charWrapper('a'))
           .to(BoxesRunTime.boxToCharacter('j'));
```

Comment: A trick that's easier than decompilation is to use `reify` in the interactive interpreter: `scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> reify { 'a' to 'j' }
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[Char]] = Expr[scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[Char]](Predef.charWrapper('a').to('j'))`

Answer (score 0):

answering your 1st question- yes both are same
2nd- .to method is a method of ScalaNumberProxy trait and .to gives a immutable.NumericRange type. 
you can check as - val p=('a'.to('j'))   or val p= 'a'to 'j'
to know the type of p